# Using repaint() to draw on JPanel which is added to JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Attempting to draw my rectangle across the screen horizontally in realtime. When I run this I get nothing but the JFrame. I'm not sure what I am missing aside from maybe some type of threading freeze to redraw the shape maybe?

```
public class ScreenTest extends JFrame {
    
    int rectY = 50;
    
    public ScreenTest()
    {
        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(80, rectY, 50, 50);
       }
    }
    
    public void Draw()
    {
        DrawPanel test = new DrawPanel();
        add(test);
        
        while (rectY < 200)
        {
            rectY = rectY + 10;
            test.repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScreenTest myWindow = new ScreenTest(); 
        myWindow.Draw();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer thank you for the documentation. Is JSwing the same as a JFrame?

Comment: "Swing" is the name of the API, `JFrame` is class within that API

Comment: Great thanks. Will take a look. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.

What this means is, you should not perform any kind of long running or blocking operations within the "Event Dispatching Thread", as this will stop the UI from been painted or responding to new events.

It also means you should not update the UI, or any state the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Your code "is" working, but because the `while-loop` can run so fast, it's completing before the window is realised on the screen (visible and updatable).  Swing is also optimised, so all the `repaint` calls are likely been consolidated into a single repaint pass.

A better solution might to start with Swing `Timer, which acts as a pseudo repeating loop, but which is called on within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

## Runnable Example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ScreenTest extends JFrame {

    public ScreenTest() {
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        int rectY = 50;
        private Timer timer;

        // This is just convince 
        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer = new Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    rectY += 1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            // Otherwise it disappears to fast
            timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
            timer = null;
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(80, rectY, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void Draw() {
        DrawPanel test = new DrawPanel();
        add(test);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScreenTest myWindow = new ScreenTest();
                myWindow.Draw();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This is really great stuff. Thanks so much for the information. Will take the time and dissect this. This is just what I was looking for I have not done in graphical programming in Java in quite a few years so I have forgotten everything. Thanks again friend.

Answer (score 0):

it is working but is so fast that you can't see it, you need to make the loop which changes the Y coordinate slower with a delay. to solve it i used Thread.sleep() in the while loop:

```java
package paquete;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenTest extends JFrame {

    int rectY = 50;

    public ScreenTest()
    {
        setSize(300,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(80, rectY, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void Draw() throws InterruptedException {
        DrawPanel test = new DrawPanel();
        add(test);

        while (rectY < 200)
        {
            rectY = rectY + 10;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            test.repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScreenTest myWindow = new ScreenTest();
        myWindow.Draw();
    }

}
```

i hope this helps you, you can change the duration changing the number inside the argument of Thread.sleep()

Comment: You're updating the state of the value from one thread and reading in another, this could produce a dirty read/write scenario.  There's also a timing issue and possible optimisation with the `RepaintManager`, where by it might "skip" some of the updates.  As general rule, don't update the UI or a state the UI relies from out side the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: i agree, but is evident that he is a begginer i just wanted to answer only the question as simple as posible, your correction is appreciated thank you, and obout your answer you should had used lambdas, has been so long since java 8, regards.

Comment: *"evident that he is a begginer" - Then maybe it's our responsibility to provide guidance on the "best" approach to solving their issues, rather then leading down paths which might cause issues later, don't you think ;)

Comment: yes you´re right, like using lambdas by example

Comment: @matt020java I'm a software engineer for a living, but never practice graphical coding jumbo, so I appreciate the validation that the slowing of the drawing was all I needed for this botch solution lol  I had to do some threading stuff when working on mobile apps the past few years but generally I have been able to avoid this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You mention I'm updating the value you from one thread and reading into another. What are the threads that are getting read from and written two and why are they different threads if I never created another thread? Wouldn't all this be done on the main thread by default?

Comment: You're updating the `rectY` from the main thread (which `main` is called from) and reading it from the Event Dispatching Thread, this is why `Thread.sleep`, in your case, isn't preventing the UI from been updated